# "Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <span>"

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, next.js

Yesterday, I was starting a new project in Nextjs. I was trying to build a login component. Something easy . But when I compiled the code, the compiler throws an error :"Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'span' (28:4)"

I deleted the 'span' tag and it still throwing the same error as if the 'span' tag were there.

```
const UserLog = () => (
  <div id = "userlog-wrapper">
     <form>
        <label>UserName : <input type="text" required/></label>
        <label>PassWord : <input type="password" required/></label>
        <input type = "checkbox"><span>Remember Me<span>
        <button>LogIn</button>
        <button>SigIn</button>
     </form>
 </div>
)
```

This is the result::

```
./pages/index.js
SyntaxError: /home/user/myProject/pages/index.js: Expected  corresponding JSX closing tag for <span> (28:4)

  26 |       <button>LogIn</button>
  27 |       <button>SigIn</button>
> 28 |     </form>
     |     ^
  29 |   </div>
```

Comment: you are missing the `/` off your closing `<span>` element - should be `<span>Remember Me</span>`

Comment: `<input type = "checkbox" />` input too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have a `span` element in there which you are not closing correctly. In line 6 of your code, after the `input`, it should be `</span>`. You also need to close the input like so: `/>`

Comment: Yes, I fix it. It was an epic dismissal

Comment: haha it happens. Can you please mark the answer as correct in that case?